# How to connect C# and Cassandra with

Tags: c#, cassandra

I am new to .NET C# and Cassandra and I am not able to connect them with each other. I have searched a lot and haven't found a clear explaining on how it works.

I have downloaded Cassandra installed it with Python 2.7, I can run the server and I can run cqlsh. Then I open Visual studio, create a new .NET Core project and install package of Cassandra C# driver.

That's all, I don't know how to create a table, key-spaces from C# to Cassandra.

Can anyone give a simple explanation on how can I create a simple key-space, tables with columns to output the code, so that I can see how it works?

Comment: have you read driver manual? https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.16/ - it covers all necessary steps to start

Comment: yes i have, however there is no exact steps, i mean they have already written the code, however they haven't mentioned lots of things, for example, what is my host1, host2, or host3 name that they have mentioned, or how do they create key-spaces, they have already written it in the code however, i have not initialized them, and so on.

Comment: that's the basic Cassandra knowledge, so driver docs doesn't cover it... Please look to the https://www.datastax.com/resources/ebook/oreilly-cassandra-definitive-guide - it covers all necessary topics

Answer (score 3):

It's five years old, but I wrote-up an article on how to use Cassandra as a backend for a ASP.NET MVC project: http://www.aaronstechcenter.com/aspnet_mvc_cassandra.php

My Git repo for the article is still out there, too: https://github.com/aploetz/ShipCrew

The meat of it will be in the [CassandraDAO.cs](https://github.com/aploetz/ShipCrew/blob/master/ShipCrew/DAO/CassandraDAO.cs):

```
private Cluster Connect() {
    string user = getAppSetting("cassandraUser");
    string pwd = getAppSetting("cassandraPassword");
    string[] nodes = getAppSetting("cassandraNodes").Split(',');

    QueryOptions queryOptions = new QueryOptions().SetConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.One);


    Cluster cluster = Cluster.Builder()
        .AddContactPoints(nodes)
        .WithCredentials(user, pwd)
        .WithQueryOptions(queryOptions)
        .Build();

    return cluster;
}
```

I'm sure the driver versions are way out-of-date, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: .net core version of the same is available anywhere?

Comment: @Sebastian check the main driver page for more info: https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/csharp-driver/3.16/